# How to find unique least number of moduli when performing arithmetic addition of two integers using Chinese Remainder theorem?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, chinese-remainder-theorem

Here's my problem.
I have to find the sum of 123456 and 987456 using chinese remainder theorem with least moduli.
We know sum = 123456+987456=1,110,912.
Let me assume that we have to use n number of moduli m1,m2,...mn(pairwise relatively prime to represent the integers as n tuple). Eg: If I assume m1=99,m2=98,m3=97,m4=95 then
(123456)=(3,74,72,51).
Similarly for 987456 and the sum.
I also know that sum < m1*m2*m3*m4.
And I get system of linear congruences. Now my question is basically how to find the m1...mn which are pairwise and also the smallest combination possible (unique) so that it is just greater than the sum. Eg: I could have also taken m1=81,m2=83,m3=85,m4=89 that satisfies the above condition.
Surely there are other combinations as well.
**Is there any theorem where can I find smallest number of moduli such that I don't have to do hit and trial to search for moduli as it is very time consuming?**
Here's one example of such problem in the book Discrete maths by Rosen.
[Using chinese remainder theorem to do large integer arithmetic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3foBw.png)

In the book , it basically tells us to do with moduli 99,98,97,95. However it gives no idea about how to find smallest combination of moduli we can take.

Comment: What do you mean by "least moduli" and why do you need to find the sum using the Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: by least moduli I  mean the smallest combinations of moduli possible for eg. In my example 81,83,85,89 are smaller moduli than 99,98,97,95 and both of them can be used.  Surely there are other combinations of moduli more smaller than these that satisfy the condition . So I basically want to find out the smallest combination of those moduli.

Comment: So I basically want to find out the smallest combination of those moduli. I need to find out this because I am CS major and we use chinese remainder theorem to break down large integers to smaller form so as to leverage parallel processing for faster computation. My teacher gave me this assignment but he said go for hit and trial but I am not satisfied with that approach

Comment: And why do you suppose your teacher told you that? I don't know, but I can speculate. Maybe because the better approaches, if any exist, are simply too advanced for you right now.

Comment: I am from India and our teachers aren't that great. I asked them if there was any way to figure it out but he said he just knew the hit and trial way. I even don't know why he he gave us the assignment in the first place to be honest. But I found it interesting .  I tried to do some internet search but sadly I couldn't get what I wanted. So I thought if someone from this site could help me.

Comment: In any case, you need to give more details regarding the problem and your attempts at solving it. In particular, it is unclear what exactly you mean by "hit and trial." Where did your examples come from?

Comment: What are you trying to minimize? The number of moduli? (Do you want $4$ moduli or can you have more or fewer?) The smallest of the moduli? The largest of the moduli? Something else? If you want four numbers of about the same size, take $\sqrt[4]{1110912}\approx 32.46$ so the numbers are going to be "around" $32-33$ and easily you find that $29,31,35,37$ fit the bill - yes it is still "trial and error" but it didn't take more than 2-3 trials.

Comment: @StinkingBishop .  I am assuming that the number of moduli will already be provided to us how many to use (like n=4,5,6) n=4 in our case. I just want to find generalized formula for finding smallest combination of moduli given that number of moduli to be used will be in the question.  How to generalize it ? And could you please elaborate more about your solving technique. Does that mean if I have n=3 number of moduli to solve the same problem I have to do cube root of 1110912

Comment: You would take the cube root, yes.

Comment: @StinkingBishop  you got my idea. Let me assume that m1,m2,m3 and m4 be the unique smallest combination of moduli  and let (x1,x2,x3,x4) be other combination of moduli then none of the x1 ,x2, x3 or x4 could be greater than any of m1,m2,m3 and m4 . Even though few x might be smaller than any of m1,m2,m3,m4 it is allowed . Just a hypothetical example if my unique solution is (29,31,35,37) then if possible another solution is (2,57,23,31). Since 57 is greater than at least one of m1,m2,m3,m4 , I will discard the solution . And sorry for terrible maths .  I am still in junior year.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need Method 4. Giving other methods as well.

**Method 1:**

First, there are infinitely many primes. So, we can always find primes greater than the sum $a+b$ where $a = 123456$ and $b = 987456$ as given.

It so happens $1110913, 1110917, 1110919, 1110929, 1110931, \cdots$ are all greater than $a+b$ and are prime. Coincidentally, $1110913 = a+b+1$.

Similarly, we have $2, 3, 5, \cdots, 1110859, 1110881, 1110887$ as primes less than $a+b$. If we take $\{2,1110887\}$ as the moduli, the sum will lie within the range $(0, 2 \times 1110887-1)$.

**Method 2:**

Another way is to construct the modulii set by taking successive numbers and taking them into the modulii set only if it is relatively prime to the running product of the items in the modulii set.

For e.g., You start with $\{2\}$. Then check the numbers $3,4,5,\cdots$ to see if they are relatively prime. You can do this using the GCD algorithm. $\gcd(3,2)=1$. So, we add that to our set which is now $\{2,3\}$ and the running product is $6$ which is less than $a+b$. If we continue this way, we will get $\{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19\}$. The product upto $17$ is $510510$ and upto $19$ is $9699690$ and our sum $a+b$ lies in this range. So, this modulii set will work.

**Method 3:**

The set we constructed has *small* primes. If we want *small* primes and the size of the set to also be small, one way to do that would be to remove smaller primes whose product is lesser than the largest prime in the set. For eg: when $7$ was added to the set, $2,3$ can be removed since $2\cdot 3 \lt 7$. So the set is $\{5,7\}$. We can continue building the set this way.

**Method 4:**

Another way is to use the inequality

$$
p < \lfloor \sqrt{a+b} \rfloor < \lfloor \sqrt{pq} \rfloor < q < a+b < pq 
$$

We start with $\lfloor \sqrt{a+b} \rfloor$ and then search for primes in its neighborbood (both below and above). The first such primes are $p$ and $q$ respectively and $\{p,q\}$ will be *small* and the size of the set is just $2$. No other set of size $2$ exists with the product being less than this $pq$.

If you want primes, you need a primality test for checking the candidates.

You don't need primes, just relatively prime integers. So, the search can be done using successive values and checking for coprimality using the GCD algorithm which is very fast [$O(\log n)$]. Rest of it remains same.